# LeaseOwner and LockAttempt does it work in Sitecore 9.3 Analytics

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, contact

I am working on Sitecore Analytics Contact code Upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3

After upgrading latest dlls and adding `XConnect` assemblies, I am getting issue in some scenario

1. `LockAttemptResult` is not present in Sitecore 9.3 analytics:

   ```
   LockAttemptResult<Contact> lockResult = 
       _contactRepository.TryLoadContact(
           contactIdentifier, 
           _leaseOwner, 
           TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
   if (lockResult.Status == LockAttemptStatus.AlreadyLocked)
   ```

Is there any replacement of this?

2. `LeaseOwner` is not present in `Sitecore.Analytics.Model`:

   ```
    _leaseOwner = new LeaseOwner(requestorName, LeaseOwnerType.OutOfRequestWorker);
   ```

Is there any replacement of this class too?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use in Sitecore 9 the LeaseOwner and lock/unlock contacts.
With Sitecore xConnect it was simplified a lot how to send data to xDB.

In Sitecore 8+ to update data you have to use next code:

```
public void SetContactData(string username)
{
    LeaseOwner leaseOwner = new LeaseOwner("YOUR_WORKER_NAME", LeaseOwnerType.OutOfRequestWorker);
    ContactRepositoryBase contactRepository = Factory.CreateObject("contactRepository", true) as ContactRepositoryBase;
    // Attempt to obtain an exclusive lock on an existing contact in xDB.
    LockAttemptResult<Contact> lockResult = contactRepository.TryLoadContact(username, leaseOwner,
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    Contact contact = null;
    if (lockResult.Status == LockAttemptStatus.AlreadyLocked)
    {
     // Another worker or a live web session has an exclusive lock on the contact.
     // You can't use this contact right now. It's up to you what to do in this case.
      /* ... */
     }
     else if (lockResult.Status == LockAttemptStatus.DatabaseUnavailable)
     {
      // Database is down. Try to handle this gracefully.
      /* ... */
     }
     else if (lockResult.Status == LockAttemptStatus.NotFound)
     {
        // A contact with the given identifier doesn't exist.
       // Just create a new contact object.
       contact = contactRepository.CreateContact(Guid.NewGuid());
      // Identify it.
       contact.Identifiers.Identifier = username;
       // And make it known.
       contact.Identifiers.IdentificationLevel = Sitecore.Analytics.Model.ContactIdentificationLevel.Known;
     }
     else
     {
       // We successfull locked an existing contact.
      contact = lockResult.Object;
     }
     // Set some contact facets:
     /* ... */
     // Save the contact and release the lock.
     if (contact != null)
     {
      var options = new ContactSaveOptions(release: true, owner: leaseOwner);
      contactRepository.SaveContact(contact, options);
      }
    }
```

with Sitecore 9 is pretty simple :

```
public void UpdateContact(string source, string identifier, Data data)
{
    using (XConnectClient client = GetClient())
     {
        IdentifiedContactReference reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, identifier);
        Contact contact = client.Get<Contact>(reference, new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey));
        if (contact == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Set Facets
       client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInformation);
       client.Submit();
     }
}
```

Comment: Then how we insert our code in ContactRepositoryBase ? and what is source string user in parameters?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am Upgrading my site form Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3, I am writing code to get, create and update contact. Just want to know how this Xconnect client will send contact to xdb. And one more thing what is this source parameter(any example if you can provide)

Comment: so you need to use something similar with my code. xDB API was changed a lot in Sitecore 9, you need to reuse new code and to remove Sitecore 8 code.